# How can I construct a clean, Python like grammar in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, grammar

G'day!

How can I construct a simple ANTLR grammar handling multi-line expressions without the need for either semicolons or backslashes?

I'm trying to write a simple DSLs for expressions:

```
# sh style comments
ThisValue = 1
ThatValue = ThisValue * 2
ThisOtherValue = (1 + 2 + ThisValue * ThatValue)
YetAnotherValue = MAX(ThisOtherValue, ThatValue)
```

Overall, I want my application to provide the script with some initial named values and pull out the final result. I'm getting hung up on the syntax, however. I'd like to support multiple line expressions like the following:

```
# Note: no backslashes required to continue expression, as we're in brackets
# Note: no semicolon required at end of expression, either
ThisValueWithAReallyLongName = (ThisOtherValueWithASimilarlyLongName
                               +AnotherValueWithAGratuitouslyLongName)
```

I started off with an ANTLR grammar like this:

```
exprlist
    : ( assignment_statement | empty_line )* EOF!
    ;
assignment_statement
    : assignment NL!?
    ;
empty_line
    : NL;
assignment
    : ID '=' expr
    ;

// ... and so on
```

It seems simple, but I'm already in trouble with the newlines:

```
warning(200): StackOverflowQuestion.g:11:20: Decision can match input such as "NL" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
```

Graphically, in org.antlr.works.IDE:

[Decision Can Match NL Using Multiple Alternatives http://img.skitch.com/20090723-ghpss46833si9f9ebk48x28b82.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090723-ghpss46833si9f9ebk48x28b82.png)

I've kicked the grammar around, but always end up with violations of expected behavior:

- A newline is not required at the end of the file
- Empty lines are acceptable
- Everything in a line from a pound sign onward is discarded as a comment
- Assignments end with end-of-line, not semicolons
- Expressions can span multiple lines if wrapped in brackets

I can find example ANTLR grammars with many of these characteristics. I find that when I cut them down to limit their expressiveness to just what I need, I end up breaking something. Others are too simple, and I break them as I add expressiveness.

Which angle should I take with this grammar? Can you point to any examples that aren't either trivial or full Turing-complete languages?

Answer (score 6):

I would let your tokenizer do the heavy lifting rather than mixing your newline rules into your grammar:

- Count parentheses, brackets, and braces, and don't generate NL tokens while there are unclosed groups. That'll give you line continuations for free without your grammar being any the wiser.
- Always generate an NL token at the end of file whether or not the last line ends with a `'\n'` character, then you don't have to worry about a special case of a statement without a NL. Statements **always** end with an NL.

The second point would let you simplify your grammar to something like this:

```
exprlist
    : ( assignment_statement | empty_line )* EOF!
    ;
assignment_statement
    : assignment NL
    ;
empty_line
    : NL
    ;
assignment
    : ID '=' expr
    ;
```

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to get the tokenizer to do that heavy lifting. Back to the documentation, I guess. :)

Comment: John, it still eludes me. What's the ANTLR grammar syntax to have the tokenizer insert NL before EOF?

Comment: +1 For always ending on a new line, makes things so much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
exprlist
    : (expr)? (NL+ expr)* NL!? EOF!
    ;
expr 
    : assignment | ...
    ;
assignment
    : ID '=' expr
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you chose to make NL optional, because the last statement in your input code doesn't have to end with a newline.

While it makes a lot of sense, you are making life a lot harder for your parser. Separator tokens (like NL) should be cherished, as they disambiguate and reduce the chance of conflicts.

In your case, the parser doesn't know if it should parse "assignment NL" or "assignment empty_line". There are many ways to solve it, but most of them are just band-aides for an unwise design choice.

My recommendation is an innocent hack: Make NL mandatory, and always append NL to the end of your input stream!

It may seem a little unsavory, but in reality it will save you a lot of future headaches.